# Выполнение метода до определенного условия

Tags: java, rest, замыкания, groovy

Я пишу тестовый spock проект, который работает c REST приложением, который в свою очередь работает с БД.

Проблематика заключается в том при дергании рест запросов, в БД не успевает записываться инфа и приходится изобретать такие вот штуки.

Как можно реализовать метод, который будет выполняться пока не удовлетворит некоторое условие.
Всё что я смог реализовать это:

```
class Helper { 


   static def waitForResponse(Closure closure, int size = 1) {
            int count = 0
            BaseResponse response = closure.call()
            while (response.body.size != size && count <= 15) {
                response = closure.call()
                log.info("try to get response, count: ${count}, response: ${response}")
                if (response.body.size != size) {
                    sleep 200
                }
                count++
            }
            checkSuccess(response)
            return response.body
        }
   }
}
```

Это удовлетворяет только тем запросам, формат которых - лист, да и то работает не совсем так, как мне нужно. В ответе может быть List<Мар>

Нужно что то типо:

```
class Waiter {

    BaseResponse response = waitForResponse({someMetod(someParam)}, it.someField == "someValue")

    // либо 

    BaseResponse response = waitForResponse({someMetod(someParam)}, {it.someField == "someValue"})

}
```

т.е. someMetod(someParam) будет выполняться с промежутками в 200мс до тех пор пока не удовлетворит условию либо закончатся попытки

Быть может я вообще не в ту степь копнул и есть что то более изящное?

P.S. я всего лишь тестер, поэтому предложения про то что нужно оптимизировать работу с БД мне вряд ли помогут:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте еще одно `Closure`, в котором задавайте условие:

```
static def waitForResponse(Closure action, Closure condition) {
  int count = 0
  BaseResponse response = action()
  while (!condition(response) && count < MAX_TRIES) {
    sleep 200
    count++;
  }
  if (count == MAX_TRIES) {
    # не удалось, бросаем исключение с подробностями
  }
  
  return response.body
}
```

И тогда можно вызывать так:

```
def body = waitForResponse(
   {someMetod(someParam)},
   {it.body.size > 100}
)
```

Или создать вспомогательные функции, чтоб облегчить проверки и сделать их более высокоуровнемыми:

```
def body = waitForResponse(
   {someMetod(someParam)},
   {'some-value' in someParseFunction(it)}
)
```

`someParseFunction` - это функция, которая принимает `BaseResponse` и из него достает, то что вам нужно. Таких функций можно сделать сколько нужно для разных сценариев.

Еще я люблю делать DLS, чтоб можно было писать так:

```
def body = execute { someMethod(someParam)} andWait {'some-value' in parseSome(it)}
```

Для этого сделайте вспомогательный метод:

```
def execute(Closure action) {
  return ['andWait': {condition -> waitForResponse(action, condition) }]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ мне помог! 
Храни вас Óдин